# Disable editing mode of a TableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I want to disable the editing mode you can access by clicking a cell.
[example i don´t want to allow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ggL.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Implement the [NSTableView delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdelegate/1527305-tableview?language=objc)

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row;
```

and return `NO` for the cells you don't want to allow editing.

Comment: What is the way to set the specific column, i mean if my column identifier is "name" how would be the function?  - (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{  ********************************} @vadian

Comment: You got the `NSTableColumn` object so you can check for the identifier `return ![tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"name"]`

Comment: It doesn´t word. When i do double click on the cell it allow me to write. In fact i want to disable all the cells of the table.

Comment: Is this a **view** based or a **cell** based table view? In a cell based table view just `return NO;` to disable editing for all cells. In a view based table view disable editing in Interface Builder.

Comment: not working for me. Table is still editable even with `return false`

Answer (score -2):

By doing double click on the column you can disable the option "editable"